# Selection of columns in stored procedure based on parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I need to check the parameters in the stored procedure if it is entered then I need to select that

```
i=j=k=l=m=1;
IF (p_plant_cd IS NULL) THEN
   i=0;
END IF;
IF(p_global_duns_nbr IS NULL) THEN
   j=0
END IF;
IF(p_global_duns_nbr IS NULL) THEN
   k=0
END IF;
IF(p_matrl_grp IS NULL) THEN 
   l=0
END IF;
IF (p_mrp IS NULL) THEN
   m=0
END IF ;
```

Which ever value is 1 I need to add corresponding parameters in the variable `v_select`

For eg ;

```
if k and l are 1 then 
v_select='p_global_duns_nbr,p_matrl_grp'
```

Pls suggest me how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried ? what error did you get ? it seems that you already have the answer and just need to write it in correct plsql syntax...

Comment: Yes . I dont know how to write the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable , holding column names , then concat to select statement and you have SQL select statement in v_select , use it as you want

```
declare
    v_columns varchar2(255);
    v_select varchar2(2000);
    v_result sys_refcursor;
begin

    v_columns := 'rownum';

    IF p_plant_cd = 1 THEN
       v_columns := v_columns || ',p_plant_cd';
    END IF;

    IF p_global_duns_nbr = 1 THEN
       v_columns := v_columns || ',p_global_duns_nbr';
    END IF;

    IF p_global_duns_nbr = 1 THEN
       v_columns := v_columns || ',p_global_duns_nbr';
    END IF;

        IF p_matrl_grp = 1 THEN
       v_columns := v_columns || ',p_matrl_grp';
    END IF;

    IF p_mrp = 1 THEN
       v_columns := v_columns || ',p_mrp';
    END IF; 



    v_select := 'SELECT ' || v_columns || ' FROM table';

    open v_result for v_select;




end;
```